# Can we do something about "Take the 2-minute tour ×" appearing in Google search results?

Tags: feature-request, seo

It seems unnecessary for users outside of the site to be prompted to take the tour, and is wasting precious text preview real estate. It usually happens for me when I have "minute" or "minutes" in the search query.

eg. a front-page excerpt from a search for "stackoverflow objc check if date within last 30 minutes"

[image]

I imagine it'd be done with something like the [googleoff/googleon](http://www.google.com/support/enterprise/static/gsa/docs/admin/72/gsa_doc_set/admin_crawl/preparing.html#1076243) tags.

> Text between the tags is not indexed, is not associated with anchor text, or used for a snippet.

**Update**: Turns out that's just for Search Appliance. (Thanks @Pang)

Could we instead do something like this?
https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/a/16391

> Another solution is to wrap the sig in a `span` or `div` with style set to `display:none` and then use Javascript to take that away so the text displays for browsers with Javascript on. Search engines know it's not going to be displayed so shouldn't index it.

Comment: How are we supposed to influence Google results?

Comment: @KenWhite I've updated the question. It's up to each site to decide which parts it allows Google to index.

Comment: @Sadurnias http://stackoverflow.com/a/19489890/1402846

Answer (score -5):

I cannot see where a problem lies. **All returned pages are relevant**. They just **cite** the tour, and as the citation contains the word *minutes*, the sentence appears in the abstract.

I would never ask a SO developper to spend one minute on such a (IMHO non existent) problem.